# How to insert more than 256 columns in a Open Office Calc sheet using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, openoffice-calc

HI! friends

I have table contains 457 columns i need to ecport this table data to Open Office Calc spreadsheet.
Uisng c# in asp.net

Can any one please help me.

Thank You!

Comment: Why is it tagged excel when using OpenOffice? And what do you use to write the spreadsheet? BTW Only OpenOffice 3 supports more than 256 columns per sheet.

Comment: I use XmlSpreadsheet tags to create an xsl document and i created 333 columns but, i unable read that document.

Comment: @extraneon & gvkv: tags changed

Answer (score 3):

Split it across sheets...

( But  457 COLUMNS???  smells bad!)

Comment: another option, but you're right it's messy and will make any resulting reporting very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force Excel or OpenOffice to accept more columns than what is built in. Extraneon is right that only the latest versions of the office suites accept more than 256 columns so you could try that. But otherwise, you may have to rethink what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would try very hard to make 2 spreadsheets,each with the index column and header of course,
and split the columns over them. Perhaps even a third sheet sosummarize important columns & sums if you need those. That's not only more portable but more importantly more readable for users.

If different parties read the sheet (finance, sales, marketing, management) you could even make a sheet for each of those, only with the columns for these people. This is obviously no a technical solution, but spreadsheets are designed for humans so it makes sense to format them for readability.

And if you do need more than 256 columns you're stuck to openoffice 3.0 and higher.